# How do you do simple CRUD in Android?

Tags: android

All the examples that I have read have only went over how to create one Activity based apps that allow for listing items and none of them have talked about how to drill down into a selected list item to perform various CRUD operations.

So my question is what is the best practice for this?  Is it to set an id value in the intent (I haven't seen any examples do this) or should a ContentProvider be created and used?

If anyone knows of any good tutorials that would answer this question please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you missed the [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) which talks about creating, editing, and deleting items stored in SQLite.

Comment: That was the first tutorial I looked at, unfortunately that was a while back and I forgot all about it.

Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score -1):

just here found a great didactic site with source and examples:

http://www.keikis.org/academy/android-index/androd-base-final-projec‌​t

Comment: It is a great and completed site